# Restrict user from directly typing the from url to access other aspx pages

Tags: asp.net

Hi Guys please need your expertise with regards to my problem...

My scenario is my web app can be access by users active directory I don't have any login...
once the authorized user access my web app I wan't them to be restricted in typing directly to the url by typing a particular aspx page.Is any one knows how to do it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict a user from typing in a url in a browser - that just does not make sense.
You will need to restrict access to your pages using standard ASP.NET roles or authorization, or some other method.

Answer (score 0):

As blorkfish suggested you can use forms authorisation to restrict user from access a page or a folder by redirecting him/her to a default/login page. Here is an Example:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin,User"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This a web config file that you can place in a folder containing some web pages. So in this example only users with the role "User" and/or "Admin" will be allowed to open a page within this folder. All the rest will be denied and (if settup in root web.config) redirected to default page.